# How can I call post request with body in android tor client

Tags: android, kotlin, ktor, ktor-client

I want to call an API with the body and send two parameters to this request in the android ktor client. how can I do this?

**I wrote this code but it's not working:**

```
    override suspend fun getListOfAllCompanies(): ResponseModel<List<NetworkAllCompaniesModel>> =
        KtorModule.provideKtor().post(  HttpRoutes.GET_LIST_OF_ALL_COMPANIES) {
            body = Body1(page = 2, countPerPage = 20)
        }.body()

}

@Serializable
data class Body1(
    val page: Int,
    val countPerPage: Int,
)
```

**This is my request:**

[image]

Comment: Do you try  to use retrofit??

Comment: @AymenBenSalah No I'm using ktor client, I want to know how can i send a form data in the POST in ktor

Comment: So do you want to send a POST request with the `multipart/form-data` content type  and two parameters `page` and `countPerPage`?

Comment: @AlekseiTirman Yes

Comment: I Used this code but it's not working:      override suspend fun getListOfAllCompanies(): ResponseModel<List<NetworkAllCompaniesModel>> =
  KtorModule.provideKtor().post(HttpRoutes.GET_LIST_OF_ALL_COMPANIES) {
   body = MultiPartFormDataContent(formData {
    append("page",1)
    append("countPerPage",10)
   })
  }.body()

Answer (score 0):

You can send a `multipart/form-data` request using an instance of the `MultiPartFormDataContent` class for a body or the `submitFormWithBinaryData` method. For more information please read [the documentation](https://ktor.io/docs/old/request.html#upload_file).

Ktor 1.6.*

```
val client = HttpClient(OkHttp)

val response: String = client.post("https://httpbin.org/post") {
    body = MultiPartFormDataContent(parts = formData {
        append("page", 2)
        append("countPerPage", 20)
    })
}

println(response)
```

Ktor 2.*

```
val client = HttpClient(OkHttp)

val response = client.post("https://httpbin.org/post") {
    setBody(MultiPartFormDataContent(parts = formData {
        append("page", 2)
        append("countPerPage", 20)
    }))
}

println(response.bodyAsText())
```